# Connecting ssd to a laptop without removing hard drive?

Tags: laptop, ssd

I have lenovo y50-70 . there is no msata ports or no free ports . but i want to add a ssd to it without replacing hard drive . i want to add a 120gb ssd. I am thinking if by splitter cable like sata splitter cable or pcie splitter is it possible to achieve what i am thinking ?

Answer (score 2):

> I am thinking if by splitter cable like sata splitter cable or 
>   PCI-e splitter. Is it possible to

No, at least not with a simple splitter.

SATA is a point to point connection. You can multiplex multiple streams over a single SATA channel if you use a [port multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_multiplier).  I doubt that most laptops will support this or that you can easily boot from it.  (Easily as in, it might work but you might need to reinstall with additional drivers).

PCI-e is also a set of point to point devices. And PCI-e x1 lane has some control lines, some power and one set (the x1) of data lines. Same for PCI-e x4, x8, x16, but with more data lines in paralel. So you cannot just use cable splitter. Whaty you can do is add one device (one, so no splitting) which understands PCI-e and has multiple PCI-e outs (a PCI-e bridge). Usually these are sensitive things build into a motherboard, not something you just slap onto a laptop.

That leaves you with alternate solutions:

1. Connect the SSD regualry via SATA and enjoy its speed. Connect the HDD via a port which is available (e.g. firewire, USB, ...).
2. Find a way to add a port (Thunderbolt SATA card, expresscard to SATA, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Rather late, but you could also use an [external USB SSD](http://www.newegg.com/External-SSDs/SubCategory/ID-2022) in a USB3 port.